# Invalid json response error while implementing datatables in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, datatables-1.10

I have just been following this [tutorial](http://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter#well-done). I get a blank table with an error of invalid json response. When I validate my url on http://jsonlint.com i get this error

Expecting '{', '['

When i do a `dd(Datatables::of(Remit::select('*'))->make(true))` I do get results from my remit table on the browser so the query cant be the problem.

Could anyone have an idea where to change the json format sent from the server? I tried playing around with this block of code but with no luck

```
$(function() {
$('#remit-table').DataTable(
{
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '{!! route('datatables.data') !!}',
    columns: [
        { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
        { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
        { data: 'reference', name: 'reference' },
        { data: 'mobile', name: 'mobile' },
        { data: 'billing', name: 'billing' }
    ]
});
});
```

Comment: Please show JSON response from your URL.

Comment: There is no response just this error -> DataTables warning: table id=remit-table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1. What could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything on the link You post.
I make You a question... Are You calling de ajax by Get or Post...
If it's Post, you have to declare It on the ajax call... 
Just like this...

```
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": {
    "url": "{!! route('datatables.data') !!}",
    "type": "POST"
},
```

Hope It can helps!
Best regards, Hernán!